# Sending data to the bashrc of a remote host when connecting

Tags: bash, ssh, tmux

I have a system on a remote server that maintains context and tmux sessions since I frequently lose connection on my laptop due to workflow.

The current script restores a tmux session on connection, or creates a new one if there are no currently detached sessions. This works great, however the downfall is if I need to quickly bring up a new session on the server, I first have to connect `n` times to attach all of the recently detached sessions.

I'd like to somehow send information to the server when connecting that says "open this one in a new session, regardless of existing sessions".

Is it possible to send data to a remote host, such that the bashrc file can interpret it?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it right. Some code to reproduce the problem may be useful. I use Bash on my (remote) Debian; `.bashrc` checks if it's inside `tmux`; if not, it runs `tmux a || tmux`. This way I always jump into `tmux`, I guess your system is somewhat similar. If I want a *new* session after this automatic `tmux a`, I manually detach and just invoke `tmux`. This requires the original shell to be still there, so commands in `.bashrc` cannot be like `exec tmux a`. Detaching and typing `tmux` is easy, I have never sought alternatives. One is `ssh -t a@b exec tmux`, at least in my case.

Comment: I could just detach, however my script looks for existing connections based on a naming scheme, so that they reconnect in order. If I was launching, I would have to look up and follow this naming scheme. I guess basically what I'm asking is how do I send data to the remote bashrc? From there I can write the data handling no problem

Comment: Still I don't know your exact system, I can only shoot in the dark. How about `ssh -t a@b 'exec bash --rcfile /some/custom/bashrc'`? With prior `scp /onthefly/temporary/bashrc a@b:/some/custom/bashrc` if needed. Or `ssh -t a@b "var1='$localvar1' var2='$localvar2' exec bash -i"` and let your common remote `bashrc` act according to `var1`, `var2` etc.